# Is there a way to sort the order of columns in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am learning MongoDB and I've encountered a thing that mildly annoys me.

Let's say I got this collection:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    name: "Tom",
    followers: 10,
    active: true
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    name: "Rob",
    followers: 109,
    active: true
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    name: "Jacob",
    followers: 2,
    active: false
  }
]
```

and I rename the `name` column to `username` with the command:

```js
db.getCollection('users').update({}, { $rename: { "name" : "username" }}, false, true)
```

now the `username` property is at the end of the record, example:

```js
[
  // ... rest of collection has the same structure
  {
    _id: ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    followers: 109,
    active: true,
    username: "Rob"
  }
  //  ... rest of collection has the same structure
]
```

**How do I prevent this from happening or how do I place them in a specific order? This is infuriating to work with in Robo/Studio 3T. I've got a collection with about 15 columns which are now out of order which in the GUI because of this**

Answer (score 1):

> The $rename operator logically performs an $unset of both the old name and the new name, and then performs a $set operation with the new name.  As such, the operation may not preserve the order of the fields in the document; i.e. the **renamed field may move within the document**.

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename)

It is the behaviour from [version 2.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/2.6/#insert-and-update-improvements)

Since it is JSON based, you can get any field easily. And you have very less columns.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to prevent this from happening or change the order?

Comment: In the worst case, you can preserve the order by replacing them. `replace` results in deletion and insert of documents.

Comment: So that means I have to go through every single column to replace it..? :o

Comment: No, You need to reinsert the document by preserving order - you can use pojo kind of things to preserve the order you need.

Comment: I am kind of a amateur at MongoDB, could you please elaborate your recent comment if it's not too much of a hassle?

Comment: read all the documents, covert to pojo, replace name with username, replace the document or reinsert the document - but you should think twice before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Keys in JSON objects are in their very nature unordered. See RFC 4627 which defines JSON, section 1 "Introduction":

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

(Emphasis mine)

Therefore, it would even be correct, if you wrote

```
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "city": "New York"
}
```

and got back

```
{
    "city": "New York",
    "name": "Joe"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I use the GUI like Robo 3T or Studio 3T, the columns are shuffled, that is kind of the problem

Comment: This is a problem of the software, not of the format. I cannot even imagine how you would display a number of complex JSON structures (which don't even need to share the same structure in mongo) as "columns".

Comment: I think I got to ask the question again but more clear, my bad